# Button to close cells

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells, button

I want to have a button that closes cells with a specific tag.
The following code does what I want:

```
SetOptions[#, CellOpen -> False] & /@ Cells[CellStyle -> "Section" , CellTags -> "A" ]
```

But when I try to make a `Button` (or `Buttonbar`) like

```
Button["B", 
SetOptions[#, CellOpen -> False] & /@ Cells[CellStyle -> "Section" , CellTags -> "A" ]
]
```

nothing happens when I click the `Button`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Tell the button where to search, with, e.g. `ButtonNotebook`:

```
Button["B", 
 SetOptions[#, CellOpen -> True] & /@ 
  Cells[ButtonNotebook[], CellStyle -> "Section", CellTags -> "A"]
]
```

---

You can always check with `Print` and friends, what is going on,

```
Button["B", Print@Cells[CellStyle -> "Section", CellTags -> "A"]]
```

so clicking this reveals `{}` that no cell is found. Documentation says it should search in a current notebook, (which is not so precise) but a problem is that by default a `Button` is `Method->"Preemptive"` and it seems that `Cells[]` are lost, it can be confirmed with:

```
Dynamic@Cells[]
```

but I don't know what's the reason behind that because `Dynamic @ EvaluationNotebook[]` works well.